# Issue in finding Group name of specific user in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below api call to get all the group & also the security group which a user is associated with:

```
   var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
      foreach (User user in users)
      {

            if(user.DisplayName.Equals("Tom"))
            {
             var groups = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].GetMemberGroups(true).Request().PostAsync();
             }
      }
```

Where  UserPrincipalName is email id of User.
But,it returns around 109 values and all are id from 0 to 108 (alphanumeric values) ,but i was expecting group name also.

Am i using correct api call to find group names of specific user.
Please Help.

Comment: This is strange. Should return property "value" that is a string array of group IDs. Can you check what the result is if you get this manually directly from the Graph API with Postman or the Graph Explorer? Doc.ref. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/a234hju7788/getMemberGroups   shows error response :         "code": "Request_BadRequest"         "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
Where a234hju7788 is user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/users/{user id or userPrincipleName}/getMemberGroups` only returns the Group Ids. 
 You have to use `/directoryObjects/getByIds` to return the rest of the group information.  For example:

[image]

**C# implementation should be something like this.  I didn't have a chance to test the code below**

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            if (user.DisplayName.Equals("Tom"))
            {
                var groupIds = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].GetMemberGroups(false).Request().PostAsync();

                var types = new List<string>() { "group" };
                var groups = await graphServiceClient.DirectoryObjects
                                .GetByIds(groupIds, types)
                                .Request()
                                .PostAsync();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                   ....
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Currently  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds is showing error         "code": "Request_BadRequest".                                                                                I want all the groups associated with a particular user , i.e finding groups by user ,principalName or DisplayName.

Comment: code updated.  Notice the group `getGroupMembership(true)` to `getGroupMembership(false)` so you get both security and non-security groups.

Comment: Thanks, it works . So, for the group in which security is enabled i.e SecurityEnabled has  value "true" ,then can we say those are security groups and rest all are not.

Comment: I believe so.  According to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmemberobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
`true to specify that only security groups that the user is a member of should be returned; false to specify that all groups and directory roles that the user is a member of should be returned`